# Dependencies could not be resolved with xtext 2.10.0 using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xtext

When updating our `xtext` version from 2.8.1 to 2.10.0 in the pom xml I get the message

```
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (m
we2Launcher) on project com.myproject.model: Execution mwe2Launcher of goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-
maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1 -> org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.xtext:jar:2.10.0 -> 
org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.generator:jar:2.10.0 -> 
org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.ecore:jar:2.10.0 -> 
org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext:jar:2.10.0 -> 
org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.util:jar:[2.10.0]: No versions available 
for org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.util:jar:[2.10.0] within specified range -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

The maven code that causes error:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mwe2Launcher</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                <argument>/${project.basedir}/workflow/GenerateModels.mwe2</argument>
                </arguments>
                <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.xtext</artifactId>
                    <version>${xtext-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtext.xbase</artifactId>
                    <version>${xtext-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration combine.self="override">
            </configuration>                    
        </plugin>               
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
            <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Our normal repository is the eclipse Mars repository but I tried Neon as well

```
<repository>
        <id>p2.eclipse.neon</id>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

And even added xtext repository to be sure I got the correct repo

```
<repository>
        <id>Xtext Update Site</id>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/${xtext-version}</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>         
    </repository>
```

I do not have much knowledge of maven and I do not know what I am doing wrong here. It seems to me that the repository can not find the `org.eclipse.xtext.util:jar 2.10.0` , but this should exist.

What can I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your `<repositories>` sections. The 2.10.0 artifacts of xtext are available at Maven Central.

I just created a mock project with your `<build>` section and the missing artifact `org.eclipse.xtext:org.eclipse.xtext.util:jar:2.10.0` resolved just fine.

If that doesn't work, I'd start checking my `settings.xml` located in your home folder under the `.m2` directory.

Comment: Removing all repositories gives an error of a missing requirement  : Cannot resolve    project dependencies:
Software being installed: com.myproject.model 3.6.0.qualifier
Missing requirement: com.myproject.model 3.6.0.qualifier requires 'bund
le org.eclipse.emf.ecore 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: There was no settings.xml in my .m2 directory, to be sure so i copied the one from maven/conf to the .m2 folder. It was just the default settings.xml and it didnt resolve the problem

Comment: Please don't copy the `settings.xml` from `maven/conf`, it just adds clutter. Your first comment suggests another error. I hope that the space between `bund le` is a copy-paste error. Could you please post your `<dependencies>`section?

Comment: i removed settings.xml after it didnt change anything. The [bund le] is just a copy paste error. The dependencies are all shown in the original post. I gues that then causes this new error because org.eclipse.emf.ecore is a dependency in the plugin.xml and its nowhere to be found in the pom.xml of the model project

Comment: No, you have posted the `<dependencies>` section of the _plugin_. I am asking for the dependencies that are declared under the `<project>` section. Your original problem was about the exec plugin, which we seem seem to have moved past. Getting `Cannot resolve project dependencies` suggests an issue with your regular project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It build after wiping/deleting the p2 repository. I dont know why this worked and maybe executing with maven -U command would have been enough.

I used the neon repository and xtext version 2.10.0